# Custom [keypress] + [click] action on Win10

Tags: windows, windows-registry, hotkeys

I want to do perform the following a file I am clicking on to a static directory

[keypress] + [click] = moves target to "./directory"

How would I set this up!

Thanks!

[Python, R, C]

Comment: I don't think this is possible in base Windows 10, and so a third-party tool would be necessary. We can't offer any good suggestions for those though, since recommendations are out of scope on this site. Try asking over on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi - thanks for you comment. Quite right, I found a solution using https://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a solution using:

https://www.autohotkey.com/